# JWPlayer and Proxying MP3 Files Through PHP

Tags: php, proxy, rss, jwplayer, playlist

This is for a project designed for personal use only.

I installed [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com) onto my local dev server. This is a functioning playlist I have used and verified works:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>oTunes Web App - Playlist</title>
        <item>
            <title>My Baby Loves Me by Martina McBride on Greatest Hits</title>
            <media:content url="07TheGift.mp3" duration="156" />
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This playlist does not work:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>oTunes Web App - Playlist</title>
        <item>
            <title>My Baby Loves Me by Martina McBride on Greatest Hits</title>
            <media:content url="ajax.php?ajax=getMP3Version&track=38809" duration="156" />
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

ajax.php has been developed to handle all AJAX requests, including acting as a "proxy" for MP3 files, since the MP3 files are in a non-web-accessable directory (a different drive). Here is the relevant code snipplet from ajax.php:

```
$initial = $_GET['initial'];
session_start();
echo $tracks->generatePlaylistString($_SESSION['last_results'], $initial);
```

This is the relevant code from the $tracks class:

```
        function generatePlaylistString($data, $initial) {
            $playlistData = $data;
            $firstToPlay = $initial;
            $round = 1;
            $addToPlaylist = false;
            $playlistString = '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>oTunes Web App - Playlist</title>
';
            foreach($playlistData AS $item) {
                if ($item['TrackUniqueID'] == $firstToPlay) {
                    $addToPlaylist = true;
                }
                if ($addToPlaylist) {
                    $durationArray = explode(":", $item['TrackTotalDuration']);
                    $playlistString .= '        <item>
            <title>'.$item['TrackTitle'].' by '.$item['TrackArtist'].' on '.$item['TrackAlbum'].'</title>
            <media:content url="ajax.php?ajax=getMP3Version&track='.$item['TrackUniqueID'].'" duration="'.(($durationArray[0]*60)+$durationArray[1]).'" />
        </item>
';
                }
            }
            $playlistString .= '    </channel>
</rss>';
            return $playlistString;
        }
```

The playlist is formatted correctly, because I replaced the call to the proxy PHP file with a call to a static file (see above) and the song played correctly. I go to the PHP page in my browser, and I am prompted to play the file (and it plays correctly also). I use Firebug to confirm that the proper calls and responses are being made, and they all are. However, when I put the call to the proxy PHP page into the playlist, I get the following error:

> Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist file did not contain a valid
>   playlist

I don't know what else to do, besides move all the MP3 files into a web-accessable directory (which I do not want to do, for control and resource reasons). Any help?

Comment: Additionally, when using the proxy PHP page, Firebug does show a request for the MP3 file and the filesize of the request is the same as the filesize of the MP3 file.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>oTunes Web App - Playlist</title>
        <item>
            <title>My Baby Loves Me by Martina McBride on Greatest Hits</title>
            <media:content url="ajax.php?ajax=getMP3Version&track=38809" duration="156" />
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

To:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:jwplayer="http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats">
    <channel>
        <title>oTunes Web App - Playlist</title>
        <item>
            <title>My Baby Loves Me by Martina McBride on Greatest Hits</title>
            <media:content url="ajax.php?ajax=getMP3Version&track=38809" duration="156" />
            <jwplayer:provider>sound</jwplayer:provider>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

That should work.